# Power BI: Bar chart with percentage

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to get a bar chart that displays percentages based on the simple division of 2 values. See below:
[image]

The calculation should be 'Services / Sum of Accounts' to get my %. (116,713 / 121,756 = 0.9585 [or 95.9%])

I have tried using Quick Measure, but I can't seem to get it to do what I want. I come from a background of SSRS, but the way PBI works appears to be different enough that I'm not sure how to accomplish this otherwise simple operation. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to write your own measure. You can start with a quick measure and modify the formula or create one from scratch.

I don't know what your data looks like but it might be something like

`SUM(Table[Services]) / SUM(Table[Accounts])`.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. Now I wonder if I'm leading my question. The fact that I want a percentage to display, should I not use the simple division? Or is there something I'm not noticing? I see where the 'Display Units' and 'Value Decimal Places' under Format>Y-Axis, but nothing to get my % to show.

Comment: You can set the format for the measure. Click on the measure and check out Measure tools in the ribbon.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not seeing anything called 'measure tools' anywhere. I clicked on the measure, but right-clicking on it, up top in the ribbon, and under the Format tab, I don't see anything. I must be missing something somewhere. :(

Comment: They redid the ribbon recently. You might have an older version. Either way, you should be able to format the measure in the ribbon somewhere.